# Error running filter multiple-bibliographies.lua

Tags: lua, r-markdown, pandoc

I am trying to run a [Lua filter for multiple bibliographies](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/tree/master/multiple-bibliographies) to create a separate list of references for each chapter of my thesis.

This is my YAML header:

```yaml
title: ''
output: 
  pdf_document:
        latex_engine: pdflatex
        number_sections: TRUE
        pandoc_args: --lua-filter=multiple-bibliographies.lua
always_allow_html: true
geometry: "left = 4cm, right = 2cm, top = 2cm, bottom = 2cm"
fontsize: 11pt
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{float}
  - \usepackage{sectsty}
  - \usepackage{paralist}
  - \usepackage{setspace}\spacing{1.5}
  - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  - \usepackage{lastpage}
  - \usepackage{dcolumn}
  - \usepackage{natbib}
  - \usepackage[nottoc, numbib]{tocbibind}
  - \usepackage{ragged2e}
  - \usepackage{pdflscape}
  - \usepackage{textgreek}
  - \usepackage{graphicx}
classoption: twoside
bibliography_Intro: Intro.bib
bibliopgraphy_ch1: Endozoochory.bib
bibliopgraphy_ch2: Vysevovy_clanek.bib
bibliopgraphy_ch3: Seeds.bib
bibliopgraphy_ch4: Landscape.bib
citation_package: biblatex
csl: journal-of-ecology.csl
```

At the end of each chapter I have:

```
## References
::: {#refs_Intro}
:::
```

I am not very experienced with pandoc and LaTeX so this might be a simple error on my side. However, when I try to knit the document, it gives me an error:

> ```
> Error running filter multiple-bibliographies.lua: PandocFilterError
> "pandoc" "Could not find executable pandoc" stack traceback:
>   multiple-bibliographies.lua:50: in upvalue 'run_citeproc'
>   multiple-bibliographies.lua:82: in function
> <multiple-bibliographies.lua:68> Error: pandoc document conversion
> failed with error 83
> ```

I've been struggling with the bibliographies for several days and I think this is the last option but I am open to other possibilities in RMarkdown.

I am running this on Ubuntu 20, pandoc version 2.19.2, rmarkdown_2.18, R version 4.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the filter tries to call pandoc, but cannot find it, as it does not check the environment variables set by RStudio. This is fixed in the updated version of this filter, [multibib](https://github.com/pandoc-ext/multibib), which uses some newer pandoc features to work around this. The new version can also be installed as a Quarto extension.

Note, however, the slightly changed syntax used in multibib, as everything must now be nested below the `bibliography` key:

```yaml
---
bibliography:
  Intro: Intro.bib
  ch1: Endozoochory.bib
  ch2: Vysevovy_clanek.bib
  ch3: Seeds.bib
  ch4: Landscape.bib
---
```

Please also try the [`section-bibliographies`](https://github.com/pandoc-ext/section-bibliographies) filter, which might be a better fit for your use-case.

Comment: thank you @tarleb, you saved me! The multibib did not work (it created the list of references but could not link them in the text). The "section-bibliographies" filter works great without having to create the chapter-specific bib files and only using this in yaml:
bibliography: ~library.bib
reference-section-title: References
section-bibs-level: 2

Deleted any reference section in individual chapters.

Comment: dear @tarleb I found a little mistake - it seems I am not able to create a list of references in the first chapter (Introduction for the entire thesis) which is not numbered. I think it worked the first time around, though. Also, I would like to suppress the final reference list at the end of the document which gets automatically rendered at the end of the document. I couldn't google anything on this

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. If you have a GitHub account, would you open issues for these problems on the repo? There's a lot to do for me right now, and I wouldn't want this to get lost in the cracks.

Comment: Issue opened. Thank you!